# constant methods and constant objects in c++

Tags: c++

After getting a lot of help from the internet i finally was able to write the program below, but i have some confusions now.
CONFUSION 1:
Can anyone explain to me the function of access method.

```
int access()const
        {
            return n;
        }
```

CONFUSION 2 :
I don't understand the working of the lines below in he program i have written.

```
int* ptr=(int*)&f1;
```

Here is the program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Factorial
{
    int n;
public:
    Factorial():n(0){}
    int access()const
    {
        return n;
    }
    int Calculate()const;
    void display()const;
};
int Factorial::Calculate()const
{
    int f=1;
    int i=0,j;
    j=access();
    for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
    {
        f=f*i;
    }
    return f;
}
void Factorial::display()const
{
    cout<<"\nFactorial is : "<<Calculate();
}
int main()
{
    const Factorial f1;
    int* ptr=(int*)&f1;
    int n1;
    cout<<"Enter the number whose factorial is to be calculated ";
    cin>>n1;
    *ptr=n1;
    f1.display();
}
```

Comment: Regarding "confusion 1", what about the function confuses you?

Comment: Regarding "confusion 2", everything regarding `ptr` is wrong and break the rules of C++ (it breaks *strict aliasing* as well as attempting to modify a constant object). Who told you to use something like that?

Comment: Question title does not match question content. No static methods or static objects on sight.

Comment: There are no static objects or methods here, and modifying a const object has undefined behaviour.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` usage is often wrong. Here too (through a C-cast).

Comment: So you wrote code that you don't understand, and now you're wondering why you wrote it that way?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you not legally cast a pointer to a compund to a pointer to its first element? With structs (or classes with all public) it's certainly possible; does the private part in `Factorial` prevent that?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Unfortunately the class is not a POD (because it's not [trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType)) so there's no guarantee that the member will actually be first in the object. Also using the pointer breaks strict aliasing. And as mentioned, the object is defined as *constant* which means any attempt to modify it leads to UB.

Comment: Generally, if you ever feel the need to use a C-style casting (as is done with `(int*)&f1`) you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, "trivial" is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude And at the danger of nitpicking: The cast does not violate strict aliasing: The object pointed to is indeed an int. (It is wrong for the other reasons you mentioned though.)

Answer (score 0):

[A good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282) will explain all this to you

(Your question title is not very clear, you ask nothing about "static")

1. `a` is a private class member variable ("private:" is implicit if the accessor type is not specified before). I.e. you cannot see it's value outside of the class (unless you are befriended). To see the value of `a` you call the member function `access` that returns the value it copies from `a`. (Note it is marked `const` which means it doesn't modify the class object).
2. `int* ptr=(int*)&f1;` consists of several parts. first the address of object `f1` is taken using the &-operator. Then using a C-style cast the result is converted to an `int` pointer. That value is assigned to `ptr`, which is declared as an `int` pointer. C-style casting is not the way you should do it in C++. It is particularly bad in this code as it's just wrong to convert from `Factorial*` to `int*`: it's not an `int`. Furthermore, as `ptr` is not used, the whole line is redundant.

Comment: If `Factorial` were a `struct`, the cast would be legal though, would't it? The object there *is* an int. (I suppose that `n` is private makes this illegal, allowing compilers to re-order the members by accessability; but in all reality I think none of them does that, and since `n` is the only member to begin with it can reorder all it wants, it'll always be first.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica is that really legal (I'm no language lawyer)? I mean, that would be making assumptions that could easily break with any future changes (i.e. adding dynamic polymorphism, more objects etc.) Wouldn't this be UB?

Comment: Oh yes, non-virtual and perhaps other restrictions (probably no multiple inheritance). Basically PODs (unsure myself what exactly is required). But basically `struct { int i; char c; } s; int *p = (int *)&s;` is allowed, iirc.

Comment: The cast sounds like bad practice in any case. Especially given that the question is asked by a beginner, I'd strongly say that we should recommend usage of `std::dynamic_cast` (and no cast in this case), even if it would be proper defined behaviour.

Comment: @Aziuth Of course it is terrible (and, as SomeProgrammerDude correctly remarked, illegal because `Factorial` is not a trivial type (due to its user defined constructor), and because `f1` is const).